# laravel не устанавливается пакет

Tags: php, laravel, package

почему после команды

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

у меня в папке config не появляется файл image.php

[инструкция отсюда](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6a5.png)

у меня папка проекта laravel ,в этой папке композер и папка projects и в ней файлы, может это на что-то влияет?

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: после ввода команды что нибудь пишется вообще? ошибка или success какой нибудь?

Comment: в вопросе скрин

Comment: да, но я там не вижу php artisan publish

Comment: обновил, по инструкции в config должен появится файл image.php но его нет

Comment: какая версия laravel у вас?

Comment: 5.4.36 на текущий момент

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87512/discussion-between-pupsik-and-paul-wall).

Comment: (1/1) ReflectionException
Class image does not exist

in Container.php line 729

ошибка когда вызываю Image::make(f1)->resize('100','100')->save($path);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очистить кэш

```
    php artisan config:cache 
    composer update 
    php artisan config:cache 
    php artisan vendor:publish
```